# Facebook Graph API - Getting time of the 'Like'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the time of the 'Like' using facebook api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/feed?fields=likes{id,created_time}&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It works for comments but not for likes

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/NFL/feed?fields=comments{id,created_time}&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The documentation is also not consistent and doesn't give any [details about this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes/) i.e. there are other fields for the 'Likes' edge such as 'profile_type', 'pic' etc... that show up in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) but not documented.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The docs are actually consistent if it does not work for likes. The likes edge returns a list of Users, but the User table (obviously) does not have a field for the like time. The comments edge returns a list of comments, they do have a `created_time` field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/comment/